# Td height behaviour on different browsers

Tags: html, css, html-table

Could someone take a look a the page generated by the following code, and tell me why the space between trs is not the same (Chrome > IE > Firefox) ? And how to resolve it (Already tried CSS Reset) ?

```
<!DOCTYPE HTML PUBLIC "-//W3C//DTD HTML 4.01 Transitional//EN"
"http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/loose.dtd">
<html>
<head>
    <title>Test</title>
</head>
<body>
    <table cellspacing='0' cellpadding='0'>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' /></td>
        </tr>
        <tr>
            <td><input type='text' /></td>
        </tr>
    </table>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Form elements are rendered differently by different browsers — it could be that, rather than the `<table>` code, that’s causing the difference.

Comment: Thanks, actually it is the "margin" attribute on "input" that causes the difference. Had to set it to "0px" to solve the problem.

Comment: @Yoot: aha! Excellent, glad you found a way to fix it.